# Uploading photos and videos from mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile, mobile-application

Forgive my lack of knowledge in the mobile apps space.

We want our users to be able to upload photos and videos from mobile devices (iPhone, Android, Windows, iPad, Tablets) to our web servers (website)

How should we proceed?

Are there already apps developed that we can purchase or customize?

I hope we shouldn't have to start from scratch - mockups, requirements etc

Please help me quickly getting to the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try searching on the different app marketplaces, although you will definitely need an app for Android, an app for iOS, and an app for WindowsPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your mobile phone or table to your computer to upload photos from your computer...if you are having trouble doing that then just send yourself the picture to you email and download it from your phone!

Answer (score 0):

You can do photo uploading with a mobile web application--you don't have to create native apps.  That means you can create one web app that works across all platforms, without having to build separate apps for each.  The caveat being, the stock safari browser found on iOS devices doesn't support uploading.  Users would have to use a different one, like the iCab browser.

Here's an example of a [mobile web app that supports photo uploading](http://www.crazybikes.com/mrcjava/servlet/CBB2E.M07050s).  Keep in mind that the app is built to display a different presentation layer depending on the device used to access it...so if you're on a PC it will look like a PC app, but if you're on a smartphone it will look like a smartphone app.  So, if you want to see the mobile web version, you'll need to access it on a smartphone.